# Striped Glass ball - how do I make the stripes white

Tags: materials, procedural, glass

I'm currently doing an assignment for college in which I have to create a material for a striped glass ball. I've had this base idea: [image] but the stripes need to be white. How can I make it happen? It is currently like this: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Wave Texture* as a mix factor between a *Glass* node (or *Principled BSDF* with *Transmission* at 1) and a white *Diffuse* node (or whatever node you want):

[image]